# AngularJS: Changing css of HTML element with dynamic ID

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Using AngularJS (1.4) with ng-repeat, I am placing several buttons - of which each is given a unique ID - dynamically on my website. By clicking a button, a REST API call will be performed. Depending on the result of that REST call, I would like to change the font color of the respective button. This is what I came up with so far.

HTML (excerpt: nested in ng-repeat(item in somecontainer) instruction ):

```
<button id="button_1" ng-click="runApiCall(item._id)">Button 1</button>
<button id="button_2" ng-click="runApiCall(item._id)">Button 2</button>
<button id="button_3" ng-click="runApiCall(item._id)">Button 3</button>
```

Javascript:

```
 $scope.runApiCall = function(id){
    console.log(id); //correct id incoming!
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/someurl/',
        data: {'myID': id}
        })
        .success(function(data){
            if(data.status == "whatever"){
                console.log('yap, should be working!');
                angular.element('#button_'+id).css("color:black!important");
            }
        })
        .error(function(){
            //foo
        });
};
```

I only want ONE button to change its font color, NOT all of them. So, if I clicked button 2, then I only want the font color of button 2 to change, that's why I introduced unique IDs each button to be able to clearly address them at runtime.
Correct button ID is given, the API call is sent, the `data.status == whatever` but the font color of my button, no matter which one, does not change. Why?

Comment: hey man, try: `.css("color", "black")`

Comment: oh damn! too obvious to see. thanks, man!

Comment: I might also switch from .css() to addclass() and removeclass() respectively, to loosen up the close connection of view and controller that I am having right now...